# Run MS-DOS command from java program

Tags: java, dos

How can i run MS-DOS command within my java program ?

Comment: Built-in shell command or an executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to run command-line or execute external application from Java](http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

       public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
                Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\helloworld.exe");

                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                String line=null;

                while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir");
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) eg.

`Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();`

This is the Java5 addition that has superseded `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

Comment: This fixes a strange bug I was getting from using "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()..."  - it was removing a space from a filename used by a custom command causing it to bork. But using ProcessBuilder, it works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`