# How to compile java package which does not contain any classes with main method?

Tags: java, class, jsp, compilation, program-entry-point

I have a bunch of java files in a package, but non of them contains main method. These classes are used by jsp. So my question is, if I want to make some changes to the code, how can I recompile that package?

Comment: which build tool & ide you are using  ?

Comment: use javac and jar tool...

Answer (score 3):

The same way you would compile any other class, you don't need a `main` method for the Java compiler to generate `.class` files.

```
javac <package_name>/*.java
```

If you need to re-package this code later, use the `jar` command:

```
jar -cvf <package_name>.jar <package_name>/*.class
```

Comment: I have the whole bunch of folders in the root package, and I have to compile everything at once.

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich You usually use some kind of build tool for large projects, but you can just apply the code above to all of your folders. That is basically what the build tools do anyway.

Comment: You could create an array of all of your folder names, loop through the array and call the command for each one.

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich Not unless you use a build tool like Maven or Ant.

Comment: @Dzmitry You could do it programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053766/run-ms-dos-command-from-java-program

Comment: the other thing is that all that code tied, so when I try to compile a folder, it throws a lot of errors about missing classes

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich If there is a specific build order that needs to happen I would definitely look into Maven or Ant, otherwise you will have to order them by hand. It sucks, but that is kind of just how it is.